# aframe - Set camera position at runtime

Tags: webvr, aframe

In a a-scene, I try to change my camera position at runtime. The DOM property changes but the camera does not move.

What could have I missed ?

my js code:
`document.querySelector('#myCameraPosition').setAttribute('position', '0 0 0');`

My a-scene:

```
    <a-entity id="myCameraPosition" position="0 0 50">
        <a-entity id="myCamera" camera look-controls keyboard-controls>
        </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
```

Answer (score 9):

Create a wrapper entity around the camera:

```
<a-entity id='cameraWrapper' position="0 0 0">
  <a-camera></a-camera>
</a-entity>
```

Then change position of the wrapper:

```
document.querySelector("#cameraWrapper").object3D.position.set(1, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Four years later... this worked great - thanks! I was going mad trying to figure out how to programtically move the camera when VR mode is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Had to set "look-controls" to false for javascript rotation control, otherwise wouldn't work :

```
function resetView(el){
  el.setAttribute('look-controls','false');
  el.setAttribute('rotation',{x:0,y:0,z:0});
  el.setAttribute('look-controls','true');
}
```

Comment: This should be `setAttribute('look-controls', 'enabled', false)` and vice-versa for `true`.

Comment: @ngokevin this doesn't work.. with or without what you added.

Answer (score 1):

On the example below I can change the position of the camera entity's parent and it works as expected:

https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/helloworld/

Is any of the openearthview or acceleration components writing the position of the camera entitiy's parent? They might be overwritting its position.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('myCameraPosition').setAttribute('position', {x:0, y:0, z:0});
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#myCameraPosition').setAttribute('position', {x:0, y:0, z:0});
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to position you can directly change the camera position(unlike rotation where you need a wrapper entity).
so

```
document.getElementById('myCameraPosition').setAttribute('position', {x:0, y:0, z:0});
```

should work