# how to reset camera position on enter VR?

Tags: aframe, webvr

How can I reset the camera position when the user clicks the enter VR button in an A-Frame scene?

I set a nice camera position for desktop `wasd-controls` users, but want to reset the `position` and `rotation` when a Vive user enters VR.

I followed the pattern of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38961273/1732222) to setup the camera initially:

```
  <!-- Player -->
  <a-entity id='cameraWrapper' position='1 1.8034 1' rotation='-35 40 0'>
    <a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls="fly: true"></a-entity>
  </a-entity>
```

and here I attempt to reset the `position` and `rotation` with the [window.onvrdisplaypresentchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onvrdisplaypresentchange) event from the WebVR API:

```
      //
      // if a VR display (like the Vive headset begins presenting
      // (if the scene goes into VR mode)
      // reset the camera position and rotation
      //
      window.onvrdisplaypresentchange = function() {
        d3.select('#cameraWrapper')
          .attr('position', '0 0 0')
          .attr('rotation', '0 0 0');
      }
```

here's a [code sandbox demo] that reproduces the problem state (http://blockbuilder.org/micahstubbs/94e06c2849b6c7c60105d0243bc1936a#mode=sidebyside)

I'm developing this scene with [A-Frame Master](https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe.min.js) and the [Aug 29](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/0BzudLt22BqGRQUExYzVoLU5VT2c) experimental build of Chromium with the `--enable-webvr` and `--enable-gamepad-extensions` flags enabled.

edit: what I really want to do is also reset the camera's `position x,z` and `rotation x,y,z` to the Vive hmd's values, in addition to resetting `position y` (which is what `camera="userHeight: 1.6"` does for us)

Answer (score 1):

Use `camera.userHeight` to set a non-VR height.

`<a-entity camera="userHeight: 1.6">`

The camera in non-VR will be 1.6m high. In VR, this height will be removed. When going back out of VR, the 1.6m height will be re-applied.

https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/components/camera.html#vr-behavior

The `<a-camera>` and default cameras have this by default.